# MySQL как хранить два разных объекта, которые потом используются вместе

Tags: php, mysql

У меня в базе данных есть 2 таблицы:

1. "images" с колонками
   id | title | image_url | url
2. "text messages" с колонками
   id | text message

Скрипт должен брать из обоих таблиц информацию об объектах и отсылать их пользователю в чат, в заданном админом, порядке

Например,
Фото - Текст - Текст - Фото

Вопрос:
Как лучше реализовать получение данных? С помощью третей таблицы (где будет хранится порядок этих структур) или что-то другое?

Comment: Как и чем задаётся: 1) какие записи отсылать 2) в каком порядке.

Comment: @Akina допустим надо отослать все записи. Порядок - задан админом ранее, т.е. это где-то надо хранить, только не знаю как и где.

Comment: Блин... *Скрипт должен брать из обоих таблиц информацию об объектах и отсылать их пользователю в чат* Что, все, что есть в таблице, да? или некоторые? Если некоторые - на основании какой информации будет определяться, что слать, а что нет? *Порядок - задан админом ранее* Для всего массива записей? или по отдельности для групп, о которых я спросил на одно предложение раньше? Каждая отдельная запись - входит только в одну такую группу или показывается только один раз в группе? или входит в несколько групп? PS. Придумайте все возможные аналогичные уточняющие вопросы, и ответьте на них тоже.

Comment: @Akina сорре что хреново объясняю :) Я разрабатываю чатбот, который на определенные ключевые слова, отвечает определенными сообщениями и картинками. Картинки шлются отдельно, как и сообщения. Теперь, представим, что пользователь написал слово "Hi" в чат. Скрипт сразу понимает, что нужно найти определенную группу сообщений (напр назыв. "Greeting") и картинок и отослать их пользователю в определенном порядке, который задан админом заранее для каждой группы сообщений и картинок. Например, у группы "Greeting" есть 2 сообщения и картинка, которые админ упорядочил так: сообщение - фото - сообщение

Comment: Ага. То есть введённое юзером `Hi` некий внешний код переварит в значение параметра `hello`, и выдаст юзеру связанную с переданным в запрос параметром информацию в порядке, заданном для этой группы. Это ясно. Остался вопрос - один объект (сообщение, картинка) может быть строго в одной группе? или, скажем, фотография котэ показывается в половине таких групп?

Comment: Да, один объект принадлежит только одной группе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, наилучшим решением будет создание связующей таблицы:

```sql
CREATE TABLE links ( id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                     keyword VARCHAR(??) NOT NULL,
                     id_image INT,
                     FOREIGN KEY fk_image (id_image) 
                         REFERENCES images (id)
                         ON DELETE SET NULL
                         ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                     id_message INT,
                     FOREIGN KEY fk_message (id_message) 
                         REFERENCES messages (id)
                         ON DELETE SET NULL
                         ON UPDATE CASCADE,
                     `order` INT NOT NULL,
                     UNIQUE (keyword, order),
                     CHECK (((id_image IS NULL) + (id_message IS NULL)) = 1)
);
```

В запрос передаётся строковый параметр @keyword, полученный обработкой ввода пользователя, а в ответку улетает:

```sql
SELECT images.*, 
       messages.*, 
       links.*
FROM links
LEFT JOIN images ON links.id_image = images.id
LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.id_message = messages.id
WHERE links.keyword = @keyword
ORDER BY links.order
```

В каждой возвращаемой записи будет информация либо о картинке, либо о текстовом сообщении.

Само собой звёзды в списке вывода запроса поменять на список реально нужных полей.

PS. Структура разрешает один объект (картинку из `images` или текст из `messages`) использовать для нескольких ключевых слов, но для каждого ключевого слова этот объект будет иметь свою запись в `links`, со своим порядковым номером.

PPS. Структура не требует последовательных значений в поле `order`. Достаточно, чтобы меньше-больше соответствовал требуемому раньше-позже.

Comment: Спасибо большое